# Why does spinach give Popeye superpowers?

Tags: popeye

Whenever the situation gets out of control, Popeye eats spinach to gain superpowers. It's been a while, but I remember him sailing his ship out of the sea on the land for miles using hand paddles. He also gets a rocket engine when Olive is far away as a hostage of Bluto and such.

[image]

Has it ever been addressed in-universe or out-of-universe why spinach gives Popeye superpowers? Is Popeye an alien or does he have a mutated gene for that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popeye#Spinach

Comment: @Valorum I remembered as well that it was also due to some scientist that misplaced his decimal point in his notes making spinach seem like some super iron food; I'm glad they mentioned that in that article as well.

Comment: Anyone who is thinking that Popeye is off-topic here, have a look at this: http://popeye.wikia.com/wiki/Rocket_to_Mars

Comment: @Odin1806 - The link above suggests that that's a myth

Comment: @Valorum That is why I was glad they brought it up haha

Comment: @Bat - How could it be? He's a superhero.

Comment: @Adamant Someone has voted to close the question as off-topic..

Comment: He already loved spinach.  His friend Bruce Banner was bringing him some as a gift, and plumb forgot it was in his jacket pocket when he had his accident, and delivered it anyway.

Comment: Note, the cartoons did occasionally show other characters such as Swee'pea getting super-strength from spinach, so it's not something that Popeye himself has.

Comment: This doesn't provide a *reason*, so I'm not posting as an answer.  I saw an animated cartoon that showed that Popeye originally sniffed a strong onion to trigger super sfrength, and discovered that canned spinich had a greater effect by accident.

Comment: Important fact - Spinach has the same effect on Bluto. He's eaten (and been forced / tricked to eat) spinach several times in the cartoons, and gained the same enhanced strength as Popeye. He simply hates it, which is why he doesn't eat it all the time.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In-universe, it was mentioned on several occasions that Popeye's desire for spinach (and the enormous strength it gives him) were linked to spinach's high levels of **Vitamin A**.

[image]

Out of universe, his love of spinach (and in particular fresh and later tinned spinach) were part of an extended marketing campaign by the US government to sell more spinach, particularly to impressionable young boys, hence why he didn't start eating spinach until *several years after the comic was launched*, during the depression-era food crisis and why he later switched to canned spinach during the war years.

---

Oh, and purely apropos of nothing, the idea that spinach was the inadvertant beneficiary of a misplaced decimal place was debunked a few years back. Myth busted.

> **The decimal point fallacy**
>
> Now, Popeye is unlikely to have known that because he was created
> around 1929, featuring in his own cartoon in December 1930. A British
> Medical Journal paper from 1981 claimed that the fallacy of spinach
> being high in iron came about because the decimal point was placed in
> the wrong spot in the original analysis back in the 19th century,
> giving spinach an iron content ten times more than it was in reality.
>
> Earlier this year, Dr Mike Sutton from Nottingham Trent University in
> the UK, [refutes the whole argument](https://www5.in.tum.de/%7Ehuckle/Sutton_Spinach_Iron_and_Popeye_March_2010.pdf) stating that there is no evidence
> that a decimal point was ever placed in the wrong spot. He has even
> written to author of the BMJ article and says the response from the
> author provided no proof for the claim.
>
> <sub><sup>[Popeye didn't eat spinach for iron](http://glenn-glenncardwell.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/popeye-didnt-eat-spinach-for-iron.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Another story I remember hearing was that someone measured the iron content in spinach that had been taken from a tin, and that's what caused the tainted results. The spinach had absorbed some metal from the tin. Now I can't seem to find any evidence that this was an actually circulating story though, so someone might have made it up on the spot.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any meaningful way.  **Why** does vitamin A make him extra strong?  Reading this you'd think it was adrenaline or something.  It's an essential vitamin.  It doesn't make people stronger.

Comment: Why is Olive Oyl so.... *fat*?  Is this the modern version, or something?

Comment: @Brythan - Because the comic was written in a time when Vitamin A deficiency (and its relevant conditions like night-blindness and vision loss) were a genuine fear; https://www.downstate.edu/peds/Karp/historicalnutrition.html. The entire point is that you tell kids that vitamins are a superfood.

Comment: Another version of the iron content story is that the measurements were correct, but taken from dried plants while spinach as used in food is 90% water and that*s what caused the moved decimal point.

Comment: @Pahlavan - That version of events is also debunked by the same source (p9; https://www5.in.tum.de/~huckle/Sutton_Spinach_Iron_and_Popeye_March_2010.pdf)

Answer (score 11):

Spinach is healthy.  Popeye eats a lot of spinach; it's his favorite food.  So he is incredibly healthy and strong, especially right after he eats some.

It's as simple as that.  Popeye explains in his song:

> I'm strong to the fin-ich,
>
> 'Cause I eats me spinch.

As to whether he's an alien or mutant or something:

> I yam what I yam, and that's all I yam.

Comment: Your last sentence won my heart.. :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any meaningful way. **Why** is he strong because he eats his spinach?

Comment: @Valorum Because "[s]pinach is healthy".

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - That's just restating the question.

Comment: @Valorum I don't see that anywhere in the question. Also, this is an in-universe answer where the other is an out-of-universe answer. In-universe, _spinach has these properties_.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Because it's got electrolytes

Comment: @pipe Is that the _in-universe_ explanation? :-)

Comment: Errata: The other answer has some in-universe which is sufficient to answer the question. ^^^ is partially wrong.

Comment: So.... Popeye is a yam?

Answer (score 3):

When I was a kid, I read that he gained the power by petting a magic bird and spinach reactivated his strength. I couldn't find a whole lot of support but Mental Floss does cover this (at the bottom).

However,  in the animated version, Wimpy gained super strength through spinach at least once so it probably depends on the writer.

http://mentalfloss.com/article/54568/15-things-know-about-popeye-his-85th-anniversary