# What year was the Muppets’ “The Muppet Movie” (1979) set in the Muppets’ universe?

Tags: muppets, sesame-street

Reference [the Muppet Movie (1979)](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0079588/).

A conceit of the film is that it tells the story “more or less” about how the Muppets got to Hollywood.  Consequently, it has a present bookend narrative in which the Muppets’ “The Muppets Movie” gets screened. And in fact, most of the *The Muppets Movie (1979)* then is the flashback adventure of the in-universe Muppets’ movie.

Many of the cars in the Muppets’ movie appear to be appropriate for the year *filmed* — it does not appear to be much of a “period piece.” On their travel, Kermit & Fozzie encounter a hitch-hiking Big Bird who has not yet started his Sesame Street career.

What year was the Muppets’ “the Muppet Movie” set within the Muppets’ universe?

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure [Meta has decided](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy) that anthropomorphic animals by themselves don't make a question on-topic.

Comment: @Spencer: On the other hand, the Muppets universe has science fiction and fantastic aspects.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Other than buying a car for $10.25, the first movie doesn't.

Comment: @Spencer: True, although I'd argue that rules out a lot of Batman questions, since much of his adventures happen without science fiction or fantasy shenanigans. :) Not my hill, honestly, just playing Devil's Advocate.

Comment: But the Muppets are not just anthropomorphic animals. They at least include monsters, aliens, fantastic creatures, as well as human caricatures. Sweetums is a large ogre Muppet, and certainly ogres are fantasy enough even if one doesn’t think Muppets are. Dr. Bunsen and Beaker include mad-science, which comprises the film’s climax — certainly growth super-science is sci-fi enough elements. Their “growth pills” are literally science fiction in the form manifested by Animal’s super-sizing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about a science fiction or fantasy aspect of the show.

Comment: So now a question about a sci-fi/fantasy film has to also include a sci-fi/fantasy hook to it? That doesn’t seem right?

Comment: The universe is on-topic, so this question surely should be on-topic as well

Comment: @DavidW - The show itself is firmly on-topic. There are monsters and aliens, etc

Comment: @Valorum By that logic so is *Popeye*.  Whatever.

Comment: Wait, wha—? Why wouldn’t Popeye be considered fantasy? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174921/why-does-spinach-give-popeye-superpowers

Comment: This makes me wonder, because we had a question about Thor's hair getting cut which is perfectly on topic (because Marvel universe), although there's nothing sci-fi about getting your hair cut shorter. Hmm...

Comment: “First they came for the Muppets and I did not speak out. Next they came for the sailor-men…” Looks like there’s a bunch of off-topic questions floating about. /rolls up sleeves.

Comment: @SillyButTrue "cartoon physics" is off topic, believe it or not! [See this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11964/if-a-certain-work-is-found-to-be-off-topic-are-questions-on-sci-fi-elements-als/11979#11979)!!  That's one I definitely disagree with -- it just goes too far.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about sci-fi or fantasy.

Comment: @Spencer I agree with that meta-rule to the extent it’s purpose is weeding out one-off jokes and non-essential gags; but even it is not as expansive as “all cartoon physics are verboten.”

Comment: @SillyButTrue And where does the effect of the Spinach lie within that spectrum?

Comment: @Spencer It was arguably “magic” that Popeye gained super-strength, but it now appears to be more science fiction once the nutritionists actually confirmed that spinach builds muscle mass: https://m.economictimes.com/magazines/panache/popeye-was-right-about-spinach/amp_articleshow/69983984.cms In any case, I’d personally say it at least wasn’t intended to be gag based on creator’s inspiration generally being “spinach was healthy.” The insights & inspirations for what was America’s most popular cartoon has many hooks that people might be interested in exploring.

Comment: @DavidW - Popeye fought aliens using magic, discovered a haunted ship and traveled in time on numerous occasions. Even without the spinach, it's very firmly on-topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Likely, in 1978. That was when the movie started filming, and Mean Mama is seen reading a copy of *Variety* discussing *[Holocaust](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077025/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2)* sweeping the Emmy nominations, [which happened in 1978](https://www.emmys.com/shows/holocaust).

[image: Mean Mama reading Variety] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Comment: So the in-universe Muppets’ film canon takes place about a decade later than real world, or it’s similar but for Sesame Street debuting a decade later?!? 

Comment: @SillybutTrue: [We've discussed Sesame Street-Muppets canonicity before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244838/is-sesame-street-canonical-to-the-muppet-show), but [Muppets canon has always been very loose](https://muppetmindsetarchives.com/2017/05/01/does-muppet-canon-exist/).

Comment: So... a real **loose canon**, eh?

Comment: @Lexible Ba-dum tish.

Comment: @SillybutTrue I think you meant “Wakka wakka”

Comment: @SillybutTrue Maybe Big Bird was returning from a sabbatical?

Comment: Well I just watched it and he actually talks about being his dream of getting into public television, so I don’t think that can be any headcanon fix for 1979 Big Bird; also, if Sesame Street had been going strong for any amount of years before a break, Kermit & Fozzy would probably have recognized him?